# Huh? My comment and vote were removed, and not by me

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101405/finding-the-shortest-number-of-segments-needed-to-connect-two-graphs-whose-edges), but at the time the content of the question was a linked .png file that was simply a picture of plain text. I voted the question down and posted a comment to the OP asking him to take the time to write the question if he expects others to take the time to answer it. Looking at the question now, it has been revised as I suggested, but both my comment and down vote are gone (I split the vote and it is 0-0, so it isn't that my vote was cancelled out). Any idea what happened here?

I know that moderators can remove comments (perhaps someone did?) but can they remove votes as well? That seems odd.

As a side note, it would be nice if our "activity" included events that have been deleted, at least for 5 minutes or so. But that's another issue.

Comment: I had a 'funny' comment of mine removed recently. Can moderators remove comments (I suppose so)? This happened on Cooking bye the way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not that your comment and vote were removed, it's that the question you actually commented on ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101291/how-do-you-find-the-fewest-number-of-segments-to-connect-to-shapes-whose-edges-l)) was deleted...the corrected question is actually an entirely new question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101405/finding-the-shortest-number-of-segments-needed-to-connect-two-graphs-whose-edges)) from the same user.

Comment: That makes more sense than any of my theories. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

> […] but can they remove votes as well?

No, they cannot. They cannot remove all the votes given to a post, or the vote given from a specific user to a post.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the accepted answer by stating that questions can be removed from public view by being flagged (I have 7 left apparently).  And of course (as always) Developers and Diamond Moderators can out-right remove a comment if need be (passwords, SSN, "***sekrit stuff***".)